# WMI Console opening and closing when running exe file created using python code and pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, wmi

I have a python file as <kbd>battery_perc.pyw</kbd>:

```
import subprocess
import time
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def say_pc(txt):
    engine.say(txt)
    engine.runAndWait()

while True:
    say_pc(str(int(subprocess.run(["WMIC", "PATH", "Win32_Battery", "Get", "EstimatedChargeRemaining"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode().split("\n")[1][:3].strip())))
    time.sleep(10)
```

I created `exe` file using below:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole  'battery_perc.pyw'
```

When I am running the *battery_perc.exe*, it works but every 10 seconds **WMI Console** is opened and closed immediately, just like its blinking.